# Azure DSC Extension mounts data disk incorrectly on Windows VM

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I am using Terraform to provision Azure VM. All seems working fine except Azure DSC extension to mount the data disks. I provide below details to DSC to mount two data disks to the vm.

{
"AllocationUnitSize":"4",
"DriveLetter":"E",
"Label":"Binaries",
"caching":"None",
**"disk_size_gb":"32",**
"lun":"0",
"managed_disk_type":"StandardSSD_LRS",
"write_accelerator_enabled":"false"
}

{
"AllocationUnitSize":"64",
"DriveLetter":"F",
"Label":"Data",
"caching":"ReadOnly",
**"disk_size_gb":"256",**
"lun":"1",
"managed_disk_type":"StandardSSD_LRS",
"write_accelerator_enabled":"false"
}

But if I check disks on the VM after running DSC, 32GB disk gets Drive letter *F:* Label *Data*, Allocation unit *64* which provided for 256GB data disk.

[data disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liDmF.png)

If I have more than two data disks, then DSC mounts them randomly with details suppose to be for other disks.

Below is the terraform code snippet used to provision DSC extension,

```html
resource azurerm_virtual_machine_extension "vm_extention" {
    lifecycle {
        ignore_changes                      = [ settings, protected_settings ]
    }
    name                                    = "DesireStateConfiguration"
    virtual_machine_id                      = var.vm_id
    publisher                               = "Microsoft.Powershell"
    type                                    = "DSC"
    type_handler_version                    = "2.80"

    auto_upgrade_minor_version              = false
    settings                                = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "wmfVersion"                        : "latest",
        "configuration": {
            "url"                           : "${var.DSC_config.url}",
            "script"                        : "${var.DSC_config.script}",
            "function"                      : "${var.DSC_config.function}"
        },

        "configurationArguments": {
            "DataDisks"                     : ${jsonencode( var.disk_configurations )},
            "mountDisks"                    : ${var.mountDisks}
        }
    }
SETTINGS
    protected_settings                      = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
        "configurationUrlSasToken"          : "${var.sas_token}"
    }
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

FYI: If I check the terraform state file, it shows correct information as I input to DSC and seems nothing wrong until I login VM to check disk mount details.

**Update**:

I also noticed this issue happens when LUN number doesn't show in order on the portal [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAN7L.png)

We are using Disk Number to get the Disk Id to pass to the DSC script for disk mount as below.

```
            foreach( $disk in $disks )
        {
            $lun = [int]$disk.Lun
            $query  = "SELECT Index FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='SCSI' AND SCSILogicalUnit='" + $lun + "'"
            $diskId = ( Get-CimInstance -Query $query ).Index
            $partitionStyle  = ( Get-Disk -Number $diskId -ErrorAction Stop ).PartitionStyle

            if ( $partitionStyle -ieq "RAW" )
            {                  

                WaitForDisk "LUN_$lun"
                {
                    DiskId = [uint32]$diskId
                    RetryIntervalSec = 20
                    RetryCount = 7
                }
                Disk "LUN_$lun"
                {
                    DriveLetter        = $disk.DriveLetter
                    DiskId             = [uint32]$diskId
                    FSLabel            = $disk.Label
                    AllocationUnitSize = [float]$disk.AllocationUnitSize
                    DependsOn          = "[WaitForDisk]LUN_$lun"
                }
            } else { Write-Output "Disk is already mounted" }
        }
```

If LUN number shows in correct order on the portal then above script works fine and mount the disks as expected. I am using azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment to mount the data disks but couldn't find any way to control the LUN ordering.

Comment: Can you please share the full code so it will easy to test in my environment.

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT Thanks for getting back on this question. I have edited the main question with some update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working using disk UniqueId instead of disk number. Below is the updated code

```
 foreach( $disk in $disks )
    {
        $lun = [int]$disk.Lun
        $DiskInfo = Get-Disk | Where Location -Like "*LUN $LUN"                
        $DiskId = $DiskInfo.UniqueId
        $partitionStyle  = $DiskInfo.PartitionStyle

        if ( $partitionStyle -ieq "RAW" )
        { 
            WaitForDisk "LUN_$lun"
            {
                DiskId           = $DiskId
                DiskIdType       = 'UniqueId'
                RetryIntervalSec = 20
                RetryCount       = 7
            }
            Disk "LUN_$lun"
            {
                DriveLetter        = $disk.DriveLetter
                DiskId             = $DiskId
                DiskIdType         = 'UniqueId'
                FSLabel            = $disk.Label
                AllocationUnitSize = [float]$disk.AllocationUnitSize
                DependsOn          = "[WaitForDisk]LUN_$lun"
            }
        } else { Write-Output "Disk is already mounted" }
    }
```